# Need to reduce table width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tinymce

I have an **HTML** table with *10 columns* and its `width` nearly `850px`. My total screen `width` is `960px`.

I have a slide bar in the right side of the table and on-click on the side bar, the side bar will expand with the detail. Its `width` is nearly `200px`.

In this case, I am not able reduce the `width` of the table, due to *10 columns* space.

How can I reduce the table `width` from **jQuery** / **JavaScript**? And tinymce text editor is available inside the my table?

Comment: Do you have a link we could see or a screen grab?

Comment: what is the width you seek? cuz you can also do it in the HTML without javascript

Comment: please give us some code (your description is not accurate enough)

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would set table width to 100%; The structure would be something like this

```
<body>
  <div id="sidebar"> </div>
  <div id="content">
     <table width="100%"> columns and data here </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

and your css something like this:

```
#sidebar{ width:20%;}
#content{ width:80%;}
```

in this way, when you sidebar gets bigger, your content gets smaller, and so does the table.

something like this:

```
var showSideBar = function(){ 
   $("#sidebar").css("width", "40%");  
   $("#content").css("width", "60%");  
}
```

If your problem is that content is not readable in your table columns since they are too small, I suggest you to use the [colResizable plugin](http://quocity.com/colresizable/).

Column widths must be set in % values

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is expand the sidebar when it is clicked and reduce the table accordingly. Then if the sidebar is clicked again shrink it to its original size and then expand the table to its original size.

Assuming the following HTML

```
<table class="yourTable">
<tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
    <td>Column 6</td>
    <td>Column 7</td>
    <td>Column 8</td>
    <td>Column 9</td>
    <td>Column 10</td>
 </tr></table><div class="sidebar">Some sidebar here</div>
```

and some styles like:

```
.yourTable {
 float:left;   
 width:850px;
 height:500px;
}

.shrinkTable {
 width:680px;   
}

.sidebar {
 float:left;
 width:100px;
 height:500px;
}

.expandSidebar {
 width:200px;   
}
```

Then you can use jQuery to resize the table and sidebar on click:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidebar').click(function(){
      $('.yourTable').toggleClass('shrinkTable');
$('.sidebar').toggleClass('expandSidebar');
    })
});
```

Full example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/a4mBb/

Comment: Thanks for your example but it fix for less content and image table but in my case I am using tinymce text editor inside my table.